# Regex matching (greedy/ungreedy?)

Tags: c#, regex

I'm experiencing some trouble 'picking' this data 'apart'. Altough helper functions etc. *are* an option, I would really like to solve this using a regex only (and processing the matchgroups after matching).

This is (part of) the data I have:

```
Belgium
Belgium M_Foo
Belgium A_Bar
Belgium M_FooBar
Belgium S_Whooptee Doo
Belgium Xxx
Belgium S_Foo Bar
United Kingdom
United Kingdom W_Foo-Bar
United Kingdom M_Yay
United Kingdom Xxx
United Kingdom S_Derp
United Kingdom F_Doh Lorem
United Kingdom S_Ipsum Dolor
United States of America L_Foo
Macedonia F.Y.R. Xxx
Macedonia F.Y.R. S_Foo Bar
Cyprus (Greek) M_Foo
Congo (Democratic Republic of)
Congo (Democratic Republic of) Q_Yolo
```

Essentially this is a "key / value" sort of array of strings. It contains a countryname (which is not normalized so I can't use hard-coded countrynames or 'lookups', it might as well be some other string than a countryname) and is `optionally` followed by either keyword `Xxx` *or* `<random_upcase_char>_<random_text>`.

I have come up with the following regex:

```
^(.+?)(?:\s+(Xxx|[A-Z]_.*)?)
```

or, small difference in the first matchgroup:

```
^(.*?)(?:\s+(Xxx|[A-Z]_.*)?)
```

This works fine for the first strings starting with `Belgium`. It returns, for these records, the following results:

```
Group 1     Group 2
================================
Belgium
Belgium     M_Foo
Belgium     A_Bar
Belgium     M_FooBar
Belgium     S_Whooptee Doo
Belgium     Xxx
Belgium     S_Foo Bar
```

However, the following lines cause trouble:

```
Group 1     Group 2
================================
United
United
United
United
United
United
United
United
Macedonia
Macedonia
Cyprus
Congo
Congo
```

What I'd like the regex to do is the following:

```
Group 1                         Group 2
================================================
United Kingdom
United Kingdom                  W_Foo-Bar
United Kingdom                  M_Yay
United Kingdom                  Xxx
United Kingdom                  S_Derp
United Kingdom                  F_Doh Lorem
United Kingdom                  S_Ipsum Dolor
United States of America        L_Foo
Macedonia F.Y.R.                Xxx
Macedonia F.Y.R.                S_Foo Bar
Cyprus (Greek)                  M_Foo
Congo (Democratic Republic of)
Congo (Democratic Republic of)  Q_Yolo
```

But I can't get the first part to match. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with greedy/ungreedy options for the first matchgroup but after fiddling around for some time I can't get it to work...

I don't care if extra/other/more matchgroups are returned. The regex is intended to be used in a `.Net C#` application (in case you're wondering which 'dialect' this is).

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, with non-greedy matches, the anchoring is extremely important. In this case, anchoring to the end of the line solves the problem. Your regexp should be:

```
^(.+?)(?:\s+(Xxx|[A-Z]_.*))?$
```

Note that I also moved the optional (`?`) quantifier outside one more grouping level, so the space is optional.

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/aB8dH8 Doesn't seem to match `Belgium`, `Congo (Democratic Republic of)` and `United Kingdom` though.

Comment: @h2ooooooo: I guess it has to do with slight variations in the `.Net` regex syntax? It seems (at first sight) to work **almost** in RAD Software's Regex Designer... However, `Belgium Xxx` and other `... Xxx` fail the test... I'm trying to see if I can fix it...

Comment: edited; it didn’t account for the space that won’t exist after the state name if there is not more data.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if RAD Software's Regex Designer is buggy... It still matches `Belgium Xxx` as one match... (See http://i.imgur.com/x7DiV.png)

Comment: Strange. looks like it’s having trouble with the non-greedy modifier?  regardless, the (.net regex tester here)[http://regexhero.net/tester/] doesn’t mistake the `Belgium Xxx` case, so I think it may indeed be a bug in Regex Designer...

Comment: I went with this one; I had to move some stuff around and use single line matching (using a for loop for each line) because for some reason I can't get it to work otherwise. A "C#-fiddle" online would be sweet :P

Answer (score 0):

I managed what you want with this regex(run with multiline):

```
^((?:.+?| )+?)(?:\s+(Xxx|[A-Z]_.*)|\s)?$
```

using your input gave me this result:

```
1: Belgium                  2: 
1: Belgium                  2: M_Foo
1: Belgium                  2: A_Bar
1: Belgium                  2: M_FooBar
1: Belgium                  2: S_Whooptee Doo
1: Belgium                  2: Xxx
1: Belgium                  2: S_Foo Bar
1: United Kingdom           2: 
1: United Kingdom           2: W_Foo-Bar
1: United Kingdom           2: M_Yay
1: United Kingdom           2: Xxx
1: United Kingdom           2: S_Derp
1: United Kingdom           2: F_Doh Lorem
1: United Kingdom           2: S_Ipsum Dolor
1: United States of America 2: L_Foo
1: Macedonia F.Y.R.         2: Xxx
1: Macedonia F.Y.R.         2: S_Foo Bar
1: Cyprus (Greek)           2: M_Foo
```

Comment: See http://riii.nl/mymrc; this regex (like some others posted) does not match `<Country> Xxx` for me?

Comment: @RobIII using http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ your input with this regex seems to match all =/. http://regex101.com/r/xA3kC9 confirms working

Answer (score 0):

Try this (case insensitive):

```
^([A-Z]+(?:\s+(?!Xxx)[A-Z]+)*(?:\s+\([^)]+\))?)(?:\s+(Xxx|(?:[-A-Z_.]+(?:\s+[-A-Z_.]+)*)))?$
```

It works for all your examples. But frankly, you should get your data delimited properly.

Demo:

```
$ perl -ne '/^([A-Z]+(?:\s+(?!Xxx)[A-Z]+)*(?:\s+\([^)]+\))?)(?:\s+(Xxx|(?:[-A-Z_.]+(?:\s+[-A-Z_.]+)*)))?$/i and print "MATCH: group 1 is \"$1\", group 2 is \"$2\"\n"'
> Belgium
> Belgium M_Foo
> Belgium A_Bar
> Belgium M_FooBar
> Belgium S_Whooptee Doo
> Belgium Xxx
> Belgium S_Foo Bar
> United Kingdom
> United Kingdom W_Foo-Bar
> United Kingdom M_Yay
> United Kingdom Xxx
> United Kingdom S_Derp
> United Kingdom F_Doh Lorem
> United Kingdom S_Ipsum Dolor
> United States of America L_Foo
> Macedonia F.Y.R. Xxx
> Macedonia F.Y.R. S_Foo Bar
> Cyprus (Greek) M_Foo
> Congo (Democratic Republic of)
> Congo (Democratic Republic of) Q_Yolo
> EOF
MATCH: group 1 is "Belgium", group 2 is ""
MATCH: group 1 is "Belgium", group 2 is "M_Foo"
MATCH: group 1 is "Belgium", group 2 is "A_Bar"
MATCH: group 1 is "Belgium", group 2 is "M_FooBar"
MATCH: group 1 is "Belgium", group 2 is "S_Whooptee Doo"
MATCH: group 1 is "Belgium", group 2 is "Xxx"
MATCH: group 1 is "Belgium", group 2 is "S_Foo Bar"
MATCH: group 1 is "United Kingdom", group 2 is ""
MATCH: group 1 is "United Kingdom", group 2 is "W_Foo-Bar"
MATCH: group 1 is "United Kingdom", group 2 is "M_Yay"
MATCH: group 1 is "United Kingdom", group 2 is "Xxx"
MATCH: group 1 is "United Kingdom", group 2 is "S_Derp"
MATCH: group 1 is "United Kingdom", group 2 is "F_Doh Lorem"
MATCH: group 1 is "United Kingdom", group 2 is "S_Ipsum Dolor"
MATCH: group 1 is "United States of America", group 2 is "L_Foo"
MATCH: group 1 is "Macedonia", group 2 is "F.Y.R. Xxx"
MATCH: group 1 is "Macedonia", group 2 is "F.Y.R. S_Foo Bar"
MATCH: group 1 is "Cyprus (Greek)", group 2 is "M_Foo"
MATCH: group 1 is "Congo (Democratic Republic of)", group 2 is ""
MATCH: group 1 is "Congo (Democratic Republic of)", group 2 is "Q_Yolo"
```

Comment: You're correct, I need better data. Unfortunately the supplier of the data cannot and will not fix this... :(

Comment: Added the congo examples. Note: you have named captures in .NET, you should use that too.

Answer (score 0):

`/(?:^(.+)\s+(Xxx|[A-Z]_.+)$|^(.+)$)/gm` will match all your strings, **however**, any line that only has a country will be put in the third match (so check for this as you go through your results).

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/hK2eV8)

Comment: I don't understand... why does `Belgium Xxx` (and other ...Xxx) not match for me? (See http://i.imgur.com/mfhpU.png)